# Proper merging of queries SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have three tables `USERS`, `BOOKMARKS_PRODUCTS`, `PRODUCTS`.

I need from the `USERS` table, select a user by `ID`, find it in the `BOOKMARKS_PRODUCTS` table, from the `PRODUCTS` table, across the `PRODUCTS_ID` field found in the `BOOKMARKS_PRODUCTS` table, find all products in the table `PRODUCTS`.

```
SELECT U.USER_NAME, U.USER_EMAIL, U.USER_PHONE, U.USER_AVATAR, U.ABOUT
FROM USERS AS U
WHERE U.USER_ID = '${user_id}'
SELECT B.PRODUCT_ID
FROM BOOKMARKS_PRODUCTS AS B
WHERE B.USER_ID = '${user_id}'
SELECT P.*
FROM PRODUCTS AS P
WHERE P.PRODUCT_ID = '${product_id}'
```

Please help me to do this correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JOIN in your query to get data from different Tables.

```
SELECT U.USER_NAME, U.USER_EMAIL, U.USER_PHONE, U.USER_AVATAR, U.ABOUT, B.PRODUCT_ID, P.* 
FROM USERS AS  U 
INNER JOIN BOOKMARKS_PRODUCTS AS B ON B.USER_ID = U.USER_ID -- OR '${user_id}'
INNER JOIN PRODUCTS AS P ON P.PRODUCT_ID = B.PRODUCT_ID -- OR '${product_id}'
WHERE U.USER_ID = '${user_id}'
```

For more refrence [SEE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Answer (score 1):

do you find just join

```
select u.*,p.*,bp.* from  users u left join 
BOOKMARKS_PRODUCTS bp on u.USER_ID =bp.USER_ID 
left join PRODUCTS p on bp.PRODUCT_ID =p.PRODUCT_ID
```